# Prometheus with multi-container pod on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

I have a multi-container pod in my kubernetes deployment:

- java
- redis
- nginx

For every of those containers, there's a container with Prometheus exporter as well.

The question is how can I expose those ports to Prometheus if annotations section supports only one port per pod?

```
annotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
  prometheus.io/port: 'xxxx'
```

but I need something like this:

```
annotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
  prometheus.io/port_1: 'xxxx'
  prometheus.io/port_2: 'yyyy'
  prometheus.io/port_3: 'zzzz'
```

Maybe there's some other method to scrape all metrics from my multi-container pods? Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/bakins/5bf7d4e719f36c1c555d81134d8887eb) job for Prometheus. Put it in your own config.

Next, add:

```
annotations:
   prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
```

to your pod metadata.

And on every container, which provides /metrics to prom, create an appropriate port, named `metrics`.

That's it. Prometheus would scrape only those ports, and there would be no situation, like when your redis instance would get http requests on its 6379 port.

Comment: To be clear:    In the deployment yaml add  `containerPort: "metrics"` and in the code itself set the prometheus server to start on the "metrics" port? And the Dockerfile also needs to have `EXPOSE metrics`

Comment: Expose your port with prometheus metrics via your app dockerfile, add `- name: metrics containerPort: 1234` to a container at your deployment, `annotations: prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'` to this pod metadata. That's it. You don't need to *set the prometheus server to start on the "metrics" port*.

Comment: apologies. I meant the internal prometheus metrics reporter. (The one that you start in the code to report metrics back to the master server). Thanks for the clarification

Comment: An example yaml would be really helpful.

Comment: @himanshu did you get an example ?

Answer (score 0):

The annotations you propose should work. Create one scrape_config per port annotation, keeping only targets matching the corresponding annotation port name.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, mate. It seems like if I set only             
`annotations:
 prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'`, Prometheus would scrape on all exposed ports. So, it's enough for me.

Comment: Hi d.ansimov, Does it work for you ?? I mean the syntax you proposed ???

Comment: @OlivierDulac that is of less priority now, what I am looking for is a way to fix the problem